# Sniff serial port on Linux

Tags: linux, serial, packet-sniffer

How can I sniff packets communicated through a serial port on Linux?

Comment: If some answers provided answer to your question, you should accept it (http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1033/how-can-i-accept-answers-to-my-questions)

Answer (score 31):

There are a few options:

- [sersniff](http://www.earth.li/projectpurple/progs/sersniff.html) is a simple program to
  tunnel/sniff between 2 serial ports.
- [Serial to Network Proxy
  (ser2net)](http://ser2net.sourceforge.net/) provides a way for a
  user to connect from a network
  connection to a serial port.
- [SerialSpy](http://www.silicontao.com/software/SerialSpy/doc/information.html) acts as a serial
  pass-through device. It listens for
  incoming data on two serial ports and
  forwards it so the devices act as if
  they are directly connected. It also
  logs the data as it moves through the
  ports.
- [sercd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sercd/) is an RFC 2217-compliant serial port redirector. It lets you share a serial port through a network. It is based on sredird. The RFC2217 protocol is an extension to telnet and allows changing communication port parameters.
- [SerLooK](http://serlook.sourceforge.net/) is a KDE application for inspecting data going over serial lines. It can work as a binary terminal that sends and receives data through a defined port (Point to Point mode) and displays them on separate views. Each view can be configured to display data in hexadecimal, decimal, octal, binary, and raw ASCII. It is also possible to perform I/O through terminal emulation views and define a secondary port and monitor the traffic between two external hosts using a "Y" cable (Snooper mode).
- [nullmodem](http://www.ant.uni-bremen.de/whomes/rinas/nullmodem/) creates a virtual network of pseudo-terminals. It can be used as an adapter to connect two programs that normally need serial interface cards.
- [ttywatch](http://www.danlj.org/mkj/ttywatch/) monitors, logs, and multiplexes terminal I/O. It has full log rotation built in, and can use telnet as well as local TTY ports.
- [Serial line sniffer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/slsnif/) (slsnif) is
  a serial port logging utility. It
  listens to the specified serial port
  and logs all data going through this
  port in both directions.

Comment: You can achieve this with standard tools using `socat` and `tee`. 1) `socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0`. The output will give you two ports `...N PTY is /dev/pts/27... N PTY is /dev/pts/28`. 2) `sudo cat /dev/ttyS0 | tee /dev/pts/27` and in another terminal `sudo cat /deb/pts/27 | tee /dev/ttyS0`. Finally 3) Connect your program to `/dev/tty/28`. The two tee commands will dump both directions to the console and forward to/from the actual serial port. Note that the port settings like baudrate must be configured ahead of time.

Comment: You can save the tee stuff to a file, too: `cat /dev/pts/27 | sudo tee /dev/ttyS0 serial-caps` and `xxd` will help if it's a binary protocol: `cat /dev/pts/27 | sudo tee /dev/ttyS0 serial-caps | xxd`.

Comment: @jtpereyda it looks like your 3rd step should be connect program to /dev/ttyS0. e.g. when I connect PUTTY there to /dev/ttyS0 it correctly shows me that output in step 2 while also communicating with the actual embedded board. BTW you have a typo `/deb/pts/27` should be `/dev/pts/27`. Also `cat /deb/pts/27 | tee /dev/ttyS0` should be `cat /dev/pts/27 | sudo tee /dev/ttyS0`

Comment: This answer is very old, please consider interceptty for serial port sniffing

Comment: You could provide that as another answer. @CharlesB  Explaining why it is better would be nice too.

Answer (score 17):

I tried [interceptty](http://web.archive.org/web/20150503060428/http://www.suspectclass.com/sgifford/interceptty) ([copy at GitHub](https://github.com/geoffmeyers/interceptty)), and was successful in using it. First I ran it on the port of interest:

```
interceptty /dev/ttyACM0
```

Then I connected the program-under-test to the pseudo-terminal `/dev/pts/5` that interceptty created.

---

I tried to use [slsnif](http://sourceforge.net/projects/slsnif/), but I found that I got an error:

```
Failed to open a pty: No such file or directory
```

[This mailing list item](http://www.44342.com/linux-f1116-t3681-p1.htm) indicates that slsnif only supports the "legacy" pseudo-terminals (`/dev/ttyp0` etc) which are probably not used on current Linux kernels.

Comment: Thanks! Same error here on my embedded device. Then I use `interceptty` and did work!

Comment: How do you know which pseudo-terminal it creates?

Comment: @chwi You can give it a second parameter, which is a name of a "front-device" which is a symlink to the pseudo-terminal it creates.

Comment: Thank you. I found that by default, it creates a /dev/intercepttydummy. I was able to watch traffic back and forth, but the incoming data from the device was only read by interceptty, not my software running pyserial.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [jpnevulator](https://jpnevulator.snarl.nl/) (debian packaged) or [slsniff](http://slsnif.sourceforge.net). Note that slsniff uses a deprecated terminal emulation model.